# Hide part of panel C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a question regarding an issue I'm facing in my C# implementation. I want to "hide" a part of my Panel and if the User checks a checkbox (or something like that) this hidden part of the Panel should be shown.

What I want is something like what is used in Windows for this sort of thing. Like when you are at "My computer" you can see multiple choices in the left hand panel, and a small "triangle" indicate that there is more to be shown.

What I'm having is like 10-15 textboxes to be shown if the User checks the checkbox. My first thought was to ha a static size of my panel and just hide the textboxes, but since this would look rather stupid with that much blank space under i dissmissed this.

I than thought about reducing the size but is this the most effective way or is there a smarter way of doing something like this?

Thanks all!

Comment: Please add the winforms tag to your post or specify what platform you are using.

Comment: remember to accept an answer so future stackoverflow users can use this question as a guide :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to have a nested panel that contains the controls you want to hide. When the condition arises that you want to hide/show them, just alter the visibility of the nested panel. Depending on how your form is laid out, you might have to manually changed the size of the outer panel when you do this as well.

Comment: I like your suggestion, I shall try something like this, hope I have understod you correctly..

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
{
    panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

place this code inside the method created when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Wouldn't `panel1.Visible = checkBox1.Checked;` be simpler?

Comment: aiming for simple clear code, one line code is simpler to see, but harder to comprehend

Comment: Do you mean I should divide my Panel in two then? I only want to hide a part of my panel, it should be like a DropDownList in one way, but not litterly..

Comment: it seems like an ideal solution for your problem, the other thing you could do is have a panel ontop of the part of the original panel you want to hide but a much better approach would be to split the original panel in two and hide the part which you desire to be hidden, or instead of hiding the panel you could have the controls you want to hide inside a groupBox that you could hide/show

Comment: I solved it with a very basic solution, which I'll improve later on but for now it works for me. What I did was combining your suggestion in a way.. I added a panel in my original panel. here a added the stuff to be "hid". I set the panel to transparent and had a checkbox to hide and show it. Like I said far from the prettiest one but for now it works. Thank guys!